# Show result in a List in java? List<Shows>

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, collections, deserialization

this is an application to **view and book tickets for a musical show**.. 
i have to view & book the show timing,seats that are available and show name..
So i have to take the values from a ***SERIALIZED*** file.
I have de-serialized the file- **"ShowDetails.ser"** . but i have to store the values in LIST ... when i try to display i get errors..

**shows.java class**

```
    package egs;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   public class Shows implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String showName;
private String showTime;
private int seatsAvailable; 


public String getShowName() {
    return showName;
}
public void setShowName(String showName) {
    this.showName = showName;
}
public String getShowTime() {
    return showTime;
}
public void setShowTime(String showTime) {
    this.showTime = showTime;
}
public int getSeatsAvailable() {
    return seatsAvailable;
}
public void setSeatsAvailable(int seatsAvailable) {
    this.seatsAvailable = seatsAvailable;
}   
    }
```

-----------------------------**Serializing the file ShowDetails.ser**

```
     package egs;

     import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
      import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
      public class SerializationUtil {
     public static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws  IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Shows obj = (Shows)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return obj;
}

// serialize the given object and save it to file
public static void serialize(Object obj, String fileName)
        throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);

    fos.close();
}
      }
```

-------------------------------------------**Main method**

```
      Shows empNew = null;
    try {
        empNew = (Shows) SerializationUtil.deserialize(fileName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // System.out.println("emp Object::"+emp);
    System.out.println("ShowName"+empNew.getShowName());
            System.out.println("ShowTime"+empNew.getShowTime());
    System.out.println("SeatsAvailable"+empNew.getSeatsAvailable());

}
```

--------------As you can see ive created object of Shows..but i want to display it in LIST... how do i put the show values in a list... 
I've tried doing

```
    List<Shows> list= new ArrayList();
    list.add(empNew);
```

-----------------------------HERE ARE THE ERRORS

```
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bean.Show
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at egs.SerializationUtil.deserialize(SerializationUtil.java:22)
at egs.Egs.main(Egs.java:52)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at egs.Egs.main(Egs.java:58)
C:\Users\Makarand\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

---------*---PLease Help... Thank You in advance :)*

Comment: First, please work on your formatting. It's easy to get confused right not. Second `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bean.Show` means that class `com.bean.Show` is not on your classpath so look into that (i.e. how you are starting your application). Third, you probably get the NPE at this statement: `empNew.getShowName()` where `empNew` is most likely null because deserialization failed due to the CNFE.

Comment: here is your issues `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bean.Show`, seems like class `com.bean.Show` is not attached to your project. If you look closer, your class `Show` lives in package `egs`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, and it's not in the code that you provided, you probably have a line that says `import com.bean.Show;` instead of, as it probably should be, `import egs.Shows;`

I would also highly recommend getting your hands on a solid editor. I personally recommend [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), but [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) would do you just as well. Then, use the auto-formatting features to fix your indenting. You'll find it a lot easier to read and work with your code when it's neatly formatted.

Comment: Yes. thank you james. I found the error.. code is running.. i use netbeans.